# How to send an email to an MD5 address

Tags: php, md5

I have a database of users that includes an email address that has been encrypted using md5. I want to send an email to one of the users, and want to know if this is possible. In other words, can I send an email using an encrypted field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can I send an email using an encrypted field?

No, you cannot.

MD5 is a *hashing* algorithm, not an *encryption* algorithm.  One of the more significant differences is that you cannot recover the original text from the output of a hashing algorithm.  Ever.  All you can really do is test whether another piece of text generates the same hash, which can be taken as a sign that it is *probably* the same as the original text from which the hash was computed.  This is what password systems do to test user-provided passwords against a database of password hashes.

Bottom line: you cannot extract the needed address from its hash.

Answer (score 3):

You can not send an email to an encrypted email address using the native PHP [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function as the **to** string must comply with the [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) rules.